# Easy way to read and parse XML in HTTP response?

Tags: .net, xml, xml-parsing, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am currently using an `HttpWebRequest` to get an `HTTP` response from a web-page.  The response is in `XML`.

Are there any specific classes in `.NET 2.0` that will help in receiving this response in `XML` and then parsing it so that it can be processed?

Comment: `var xDoc = XDocument.Load(url);`

Comment: Using VS2005 so can't use any Linq libraries.

Comment: Why don't you put your restrictions to the question? I am sure XmlDocument might have good features too

Answer (score 0):

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

`XmlDocument myXmlDocument = System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(myResponseString)`

You can then use the XmlDocument to loop through elements and attributes to your heart's content.